# How to extract picture from chapter and subchapter

Tags: vba, ms-word

i'm facing a problem about extracting pictures from a Word Document.

I managed to successfully select and then extract pictures from chapter one by one with this piece of code :

```
With Selection
.Collapse
Dim curRange As Range
Set curRange = .Range
.Extend
.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, which:=wdGoToNext
If .Range = curRange Then
    .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
End If
.ExtendMode = False
Selection.copy
End With
```

The part that copy is here

```
fileName = Left(ActiveDocument.Name, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.Name, ".") - 1) 
fileName = Replace(fileName, " ", "_")
folderName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders.Item("Desktop")

If Selection.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True


Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
WordDoc.Content.Paste

For i = WordDoc.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    WordDoc.Shapes(i).Delete
Next i

Dim fso As Object
Dim fldrpath As String
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

fldrpath = folderName & "\imagesSpec\"
If Not fso.folderexists(fldrpath) Then
    fso.createfolder (fldrpath)
End If

WordDoc.SaveAs2 fileName:=folderName & "\imagesSpec\" & fileName & ".html", FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
WordApp.Quit
```

As it's html filtered i've got pictures from the copied selection in another word document

What I want to do now is to extract (in fact : select) in subchapter if there is one or more

example : I extract chapter 1) pictures, i want to get 1.1), 1.2), 1.2.1) ...

Any thoughts ? Thanks

Comment: And how is the code in the question not working for that?

Comment: It only take 1 chapter the selection stop when it encounter a new heading

Comment: Mmm, I'm still missing some logic, here. Which part identifies and copy pictures? How do we set up a (simple) test document? Are you familiar with the concept of loops?

Comment: Sorry i've added some code that will help you (i hope so)

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't help. I see no connection between the two blocks of code. Nor do I see anything that copies, only a line that pastes. This is too disjointed to understand how the document is structured, how to identify what needs copying...